# Произведение индексов массива между минимальным и максимальным элементом

Tags: c#

Подскажите, почему не работает строка *x *= i;* и мне всегда выводит *1*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Arrays1DConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.Write("Количество элементов в массиве: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double[] elems = new double[n];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Случайно сгенерированный одномерный массив:");
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                elems[i] = rnd.NextDouble() * 78.4 - 27.8;
                elems[i] = Math.Round(elems[i], 1);
                Console.Write($"{elems[i]} ");
            }
            double MaxValue = elems.Max<double>();
            double MinValue = elems.Min<double>();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Максимальный элемент: {0}", MaxValue);
            Console.WriteLine("Минимальний элемент: {0}", MinValue);
            double IndexMin = Array.IndexOf(elems, MinValue);
            double IndexMax = Array.IndexOf(elems, MaxValue);
            Console.WriteLine("Индекс максимального элемента: {0}", IndexMax);
            Console.WriteLine("Индекс минимального элемента: {0}", IndexMin);
            if ((IndexMax - IndexMin == 1) || (IndexMin - IndexMax == 1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Между минимальным и максимальным элементом нет элементов, потому что они соседние.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (MaxValue > MinValue)
                {
                    double x = 1;
                    for (double i = IndexMin + 1; i < IndexMax; i++)
                    {
                        x *= i;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                }
                else
                {
                    double x = 1;

                    for (double i = IndexMax + 1; i < IndexMin; i++)
                    {
                        x *= i;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Arrays1DConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.Write("Количество элементов в массиве: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            double[] elems = new double[n];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Случайно сгенерированный одномерный массив:");
            for(int i = 0; i < elems.Length; i++)
            {
                elems[i] = Math.Round(rnd.NextDouble() * 78.4 - 27.8, 1);
                Console.Write($"{elems[i]} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            var MaxValue = elems.Max();
            var MinValue = elems.Min();
            Console.WriteLine($"Максимальный элемент: {MaxValue}"); // лучше форматировать в одном стиле
            Console.WriteLine($"Минимальний элемент: {MinValue}");
            var IndexMin = Array.IndexOf(elems, MinValue);
            var IndexMax = Array.IndexOf(elems, MaxValue);
            Console.WriteLine($"Индекс максимального элемента: {IndexMax}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Индекс минимального элемента: {IndexMin}");

            if (Math.Abs(IndexMax - IndexMin) <= 1) // проще взять по модулю
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Между минимальным и максимальным элементом нет элементов, потому что они соседние.");
            }
            else
            {
                Int64 IndexProduct = 1; // можно использовать лонг, но если мало то double
                for (var i = Math.Min(IndexMin, IndexMax) + 1; i < Math.Max(IndexMin, IndexMax); i++)
                {
                    IndexProduct *= i;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Произведение индексов: {IndexProduct}");                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, вы помогли не только решить мою проблему, но и оптимизировали некоторые строки

Comment: `Int64` = `long`, так, на всякий для будущих посетителей.